# Automatically getting OTP in phonegap application

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am developing a phonegap application where OTP(one time password) is used.
i want to automate the OTP process. That is when i receive the OTP through sms my application should automatically extract the OTP from message  and use it in required place inside my application.
i have found the below link to do using phonegap plugin. 
https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/applegrew/Phonegap-SMS-reception-plugin@master

is there any way to do this using only javascrpt?

Comment: Since the process works via native functionality i don't think it can be achieved without using a plugin..!!

Comment: have you tried that process(smsreception)?is it working?

Comment: Since this has to do with SMS (only folks in countries that use the term OTP would understand the question), please add the SMS keyword to your question for others to find it easily. Also, do accept one of the very helpful answers below. They both helped me.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible without plugin. ([source](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html))

> A plugin is a package of injected code that allows the Cordova webview
>   within which the app renders to communicate with the native platform
>   on which it runs. **Plugins provide access to device and platform
>   functionality that is ordinarily unavailable to web-based apps**.

You can use [this plug](https://github.com/Ivanezko/Phonegap-SMS/tree/e2ae4d6fd4638073d0a1b635ba21217836f8815c) in.

Comment: That's what I am asking bro,Which is the best plugin to do that?Explain that in detail.

Comment: @bharathmuppa There are few plugins to read SMS with. I add the best one at the end of the answer.

Comment: Have you ever tried this plugin? When i went through the documentation of that plugin, It will read all the messages it seems, So if i am using dual sim then it will be like looping through the all the messages. What if i want to get messages from particular sender

Comment: @bharathmuppa Sorry, it's hard to answer such question in comment section, so please post it as a new question on Stackoverflow.
BTW, if you think my answer to your main question helped you please accept it.

Comment: sure @amin . Mail the info to me I will be eagerly waiting for your mail bharathmuppa@gmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check this website, [Token2](https://token2.com/).

This website is providing [RESTful API](https://token2.com/?content=api) for enabling two-factor authentication of users of a website or a web application. To start using Token2 API, you will need to create an account and add a site. They are also providing OTP for [mobile apps](https://token2.com/?content=mobileapp), but for your app you can use the API's which are available.

The sample usage of API is given here "[Link](https://token2.com/?content=apisamples)".

For creating User:

`https://api.token2.com/createuser?api=[api_key]&phone=[mobile_phone]&email=[email]&type=[authentication type]&pin=[pin code]&format=[response format]`

Validate the OTP:

```
https://api.token2.com/validate?api=[api key]&token=[token]&userid=[User's Token2 ID]
```

Generate and Send OTP by SMS:

```
https://api.token2.com/send?api=[api key]&userid=[User's Token2 ID]
```

BTW i did not test it, as i am not a Phonegap guy. I have made some research for your question and found this suitable, But i believe this will help you finding a solution.